# Jquery .post serialize() not sending created input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that is posting a for when you hit add to cart. it will add the new input fields for the options and everything then .post the form to update the pricing at the top....however when it does the post which is after it creates the fields it does not count those fields within the post and it is only for the newly created ones....you can see the running script at https://www.presidentialuniversity.com/synergy-business-tools/order_new.php?cid=1#top if you need more info don't hesitate to ask. you can see the javascript that pertains to this action at the bottom of: https://www.presidentialuniversity.com/synergy-business-tools/js/order_functions.js

the portion that actually does the submitting is:

```
var form = $('#store');
url = form.attr('action');
$.post(url+'&a=updatecart', form.serialize(),function(data){
    alert(data);
    $('#top_totals').html(data);
});
```

currently it is alerting the post data. the fields go in with out a problem i can see them there they just aren't getting picked up when the form is posted

Comment: Could you place the relevant JS in your question?

Comment: nevermind figured it out my post was running before an animation finished therefore the fields didn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that a fadeIn animation was showing the new fields and the .post was running before that fadeIn was complete so the fields were not completely rendered before the .post of serializing